# What is the method to reassign a data point in an int array within c++ using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

for my class I have to demonstrate manipulating an array with pointers. The first part was to output a value using pointers which I have already done. The second part is the one I need help with. With the given code, I must output ar[0][3] using the pointer p. I am not asking for an answer, I just want to know how this is to be done. Also, I don't know why pointer p and q both initialize to the address of 9 when I start the program. That's just a side question. Here is the given code.

```
int ar[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12};
int **p;

int *q;

p=&q;

q =*(ar+2);
```

Write using pointer arithmetic how would change the value of ar[0][3] using pointer p.

I will also email my teacher to ask but it is unlikely he will respond today, that is why I am asking you guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ar` is not an array of pointers. It's the most important issue in your example. Just imaging the two-dimensional array is a flat one dimensional array of int and size 3 * 4: [1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would change the value of ar[0][3] using pointer p.

First, assign `q` to point to `ar[0][3]`. It is unclear whether the arbitrary requirement to use `p` applies to this, but let's assume that `q` must be modified by indirecting through `p`:

```
*p = &ar[0][3];
```

Then indirect through `q` to access the element, and change the value by assigning it:

```
**p = new_value;
```

---

> is there a reason I cannot simply use `*p = new_value`?

`p` is a pointer to a pointer to integer. When you indirect through `p`, you get the pointer to integer that is being pointed at. You cannot assign an integer value to a "pointer to integer". You have to indirect through the "pointer to integer" to get access to pointed integer. So, first indirect through the pointer to pointer to integer in order to get the pointer to integer, then indirect through the pointer to integer in order to get the integer, whose value you can assign. I.e. `**p = new_value;`

> or will [`*p = new_value`] simply overwrite `*p`?

Yes. Assigning to an object overwrites the value of the object. In this case, the assigned object is the pointer `q`.

Comment: I believe this answer is what the prompt is trying to get out of me. It is required that I use p. Am I correct in understanding that ```**p``` is dereferencing ```*p``` to ```&ar[0][3]``` ? If so, is there a reason I cannot simply use ```*p = new_value```? or will that simply overwrite ```*p```? Thanks for your response BTW.

Comment: I suspect the "intended answer" will be  `*((*p) - 5) = new_value;` , which is worse than your answer obviously

Answer (score 0):

So you figured out how to manipulate a 1-Dimensional array with pointers. This is easy since an array can be simply treated as a pointer and the number inside the square brackets is just a way to increment the pointer arr[i] is equivalent to *(arr+i). Similar approach can be done for a 2-Dimensional array, for an array arr[i][j], we first de-refrence arr+i to get a new array containing the j members, then we de-reference *(arr+i)+j to get finally *(*(arr+i)+j), the code should look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[3][3] = {1,2,3,
                     4,5,6,
                     7,8,9};
    int i=1,j=2;
    cout << *(*(arr+i)+j);
}
```

So another example, if we have an 3-dimensional array, arr[a][b][c], to extract an element using pointers we may do it like this:

```
*(*(*(arr+a)+b)+c)
```

Comment: _an array is just a pointer_ No, it is not.  This is exactly the crux of the issue here.  An array is an array and a pointer is a pointer.  Arrays are implicitly convertible into a pointer to their first element, but an array is not a pointer any more than an `int` is a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

I find it's easier to reason about arrays if you don't try to think of a 2D array as something special.  It isn't.  It's just an array of arrays.

`int **p` is not the right type to use.  An array of arrays of `int` cannot be converted into a pointer to a pointer to an `int`.

An array can decay into a pointer to its first element.  So what's the type of the first element of an array of 3 arrays of 4 `int`s?  It's an array of 4 `int`s.  That means that the type that an `int[3][4]` will decay into isn't `int**`, it's `int (*)[4]`: a pointer to an array of 4 `int`s.

```
int ar[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
// ar decays to a pointer to its first element, which is an array of 4 ints,
// so p is a pointer to an array of 4 ints, pointing to the first element of ar
int (*p)[4] = ar;
// You can then dereference p, yielding an array of 4 ints.
// That array decays to a pointer to its first element, which is an int,
// so q is a pointer to an int, pointing to the first element of the first element
// of ar
int *q = *p;
// To get the 3rd element of the first element of ar, shift q 2 positions and then
// dereference the resulting pointer
std::cout << *(q + 2);  // output the desired element
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc485ea93b069f84)

---

Of course, you don't *need* the intermediate variables `p` and `q`.  You could just do everything in one line:

```
int ar[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
// 1. ar decays to a pointer to its first element
// 2. Dereference the pointer that ar decayed into
// 3. The array yielded by the dereference in (2) decays into a pointer to
//    its first element
// 4. Offset the pointer that results from (3) by two positions
// 5. Dereference the pointer from (4) to access the third element of the
//    first element of ar
std::cout << *(*ar + 2);
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b44f547911d304fc)

This is a pretty complex single line though, so the extra intermediate variables can help make it more clear what's going on.

Comment: The question requirements include not changing the code posted in the question